# How to set an error message out in wso2?

Tags: wso2, response, wso2-esb

I have a service in wso2. 
For example,the endpoint is `http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService`, and the request message is:

```
<m:getQuote xmlns:m="http://services.samples">
    <m:request>
      <m:symbol></m:symbol>
    </m:request>
  </m:getQuote>
```

If the symbol value is null. I do not want to send this request to the endpoint. I can use request message as response or send an error message out. I try to set property `RESPONSE=true`,but no use. How to do this in wso2? Someone can help me? Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter mediator to filterout the messages..Check the sample here[1] If particular filed is empty, then drop the message/execute fault sequence else allow it..

[1]http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/mediators/filter.html

Answer (score 0):

Use makefault mediator in your fault sequence.. Check the following post

http://techfeast-hiranya.blogspot.com/2010/04/wso2-esb-tips-tricks-05-error-handling.html